# Java string format specifier collides with SOQL wildcard

Tags: java, salesforce, soql

I am trying to do a SalesForce query from Java, and I want to insert the current date and time into the query. However, I also want to add a wildcard for title, and the percent for the wildcard is being interpreted as a format specifier and giving an error.

```
String soqlQuery = new String.format("SELECT Id, Title, CreatedDate "
                         + "FROM FeedItem "
                         + "WHERE title like '%ven%' and createdDate %s ", timeOfLastQuery);
```

I was able to just use string concatenation to get around the problem, but I would like to know if there is a way to do create a query string that contains a wildcard specifically using formatted strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape them with another `%` like

```
 String soqlQuery = new String.format("SELECT Id, Title, CreatedDate "
                     + "FROM FeedItem "
                     + "WHERE title like '%%ven%%' and createdDate %s ", timeOfLastQuery);
```